# Scrapy not identifying key from json

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the information pertaining to the biblical commentaries off of a website. Below is the code I have made to do so. `start_urls` is the link to the json file I am trying to scrape. I chose `['0']['father']['_id']` to get the name of the commenter, however, the following error occurs. What  should I do?

Error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Code:

````
import scrapy
import json

class catenaspider(scrapy.Spider): #spider to crawl the url
    name = 'commentary' #name to be called in command terminal
    start_urls = ['https://api.catenabible.com:8080/anc_com/c/mt/1/1?tags=[%22ALL%22]&sort=def']

    def parse(self,response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        yield from data['0']['father']['_id']```
````

Comment: `data` is probably a `list` of `dict`s. Try `data[0]['father']['_id']`.

Comment: I think `['0']` has to be `[0]`

Comment: Thanks guys, that got past the type error! Now another error showed up: KeyError: 'id'

Comment: You typed `'id'` in your comment.  The field is `'_id'` with an underscore.

Comment: Okay, fixed that; got this now: `ERROR: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str' in <GET https://api.catenabible.com:8080/anc_com/c/mt/1/1?tags=[%22ALL%22]&sort=def>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html?highlight=yield#extracting-data-in-our-spider) again.

```py
import scrapy


class catenaspider(scrapy.Spider):  # spider to crawl the url
    name = 'commentary' # name to be called in command terminal
    start_urls = ['https://api.catenabible.com:8080/anc_com/c/mt/1/1?tags=[%22ALL%22]&sort=def']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.json()
        yield {'id_father': data[0]['father']['_id']}
        # if you want to get all the id's
        # for d in data:
        #     yield {'id_father': d['father']['_id']}
```